# The jobs unicorn screams in vain in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

On the [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page, a clever little unicorn lurks behind the Search Jobs tab. Hovering the cursor over the unicorn causes it to pop up and scream "New features!"

[image]

Clicking on the eyeless screaming unicorn in Firefox, Chrome, or Edge triggers the **Meet the New Job Search** tour.

[image]

However, clicking on the eyeless screaming unicorn in Internet Explorer has no effect.

[image]

Comment: Unicorns are allergic to IE.

Comment: As is everyone else....

Comment: @JacobGray I can confirm that.

Comment: +2 for unicorns and red freehand circles in the same image.

Comment: Can confirm, jobs are not compatible with IE 11.

Comment: @Travis, you would be surprised. IE11 is such a PITA you need professionals to handle it.

Comment: Not worth the time. Website fails because user had IE 11? Status: By design. To note: IE 11 is only 4% of *all* internet use, mostly by government offices which do not browse casually. At Stack Exchange, where the users are primarily in the tech sector, the usage is a far smaller percent. That said, I am sure that this can be addressed rather easily since it does just seem to be an issue with an event handler. However, trying to find a job solely on being an "IE 11 professional" is probably going to be the best joke I hear all day.... is it April 1st already?

Comment: @Travis, the SO folks most probably worked hard to implement that cute unicorn effect, but it did fail on IE11 (at least for one user, so we may be making a mountain out of nothing, but it's not like it stopped us before ;) However, I can assure you that IE11 is *special*, and that if you have to maintain a reasonably-old product that relies on the obvious differences from the good old days, you *will* have a lot to refactor to accommodate IE11, especially if you still want to support the earlier versions.

Comment: I get it. My products run on IE 11. That doesn't mean anyone is happy about it ;) Nor happy about what that meant when we had to keep the other scoundrels supported (i.e. 10, or 9, or 8, or 7, or 6... well, you get the picture). Conversely, maybe this has to do with upgrading to jQuery 1.12.4.

Comment: Assuming you mean that the bug is that you can't click on the unicorn or his little balloon... It's not clickable in FF, Chrome or Edge either (all current versions)

Comment: @Machavity I respectfully disagree. Clicking on the unicorn in Firefox, Chrome, or Edge triggers the Meet the New Job Search tour for me.

Comment: @Thriggle Ah, I see the problem now. The banner isn't loading either (the unicorn is trying to interact with something that doesn't exist). The banner already exists in the others so clicking it tries to load content already there. IE11 console says `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'
tour.bubble.min.js (1,605)` So [yeah](http://img.memecdn.com/i-saw-internet-explorer-and-freaked-out_o_1818511.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug. Fix is already in repo waiting to fly to prod. You should see it fixed in up to 24h.